# Adding the text area input to a list with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am making a shopping list app. When an item is added to the text input, it should be converted into a list item with a class of "tile" and added to the beginning of the list with a class of ".shopping_item_list". Here is my HTML:

```
<section>
<h1 class="outline">Shopping List Items</h1>
     <ul class="shopping_item_list">
    <li class="tile">Flowers<span class="delete">Delete</span></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

My jQuery:

```
$("input[name='shopping_item']").change(function() { 
    var item = $(this).val();   
    $("<li class='tile'>+ item +</li>").prependTo(".shopping_item_list");
    $(".tile").removeClass("middle");   
    $(".shopping_item_list li:nth-child(3n+2)").addClass("middle");
});
```

This isn't working, and I can't figure out why. I'm new to jQuery.

Also, I need to add the "delete" span to the list item and am not sure how.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

**Edited to add:**

Thanks to the feedback here, I was able to make it work with:

```
$("input[name='shopping_item']").change(function() {
    var item = $(this).val();   
    $("<li class='tile'>" + item + "<span class='delete'>Delete</span>" + "  </li>").prependTo(".shopping_item_list");
    $(".tile").removeClass("middle");   
    $(".shopping_item_list li:nth-child(3n+2)").addClass("middle");
});
```

However, in my jquery, I have functions for the classes "tile" and "delete" that are not working for newly added items.

```
// hide delete button
$(".delete").hide();

// delete square
$(".tile").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".delete").toggle();
});

$(".tile").on("click", ".delete", function() {
    $(this).closest("li.tile").remove(); 
    $(".tile").removeClass("middle");   
    $(".shopping_item_list li:nth-child(3n+2)").addClass("middle");
});

// cross off list 
$(".tile").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("deleteAction");
});
```

The new items, which have these classes applied aren't using these functions at all. Do I need to add the functions below the add item? Does the order in which they appear in my js file matter? Do I need to add some kind of function?

Comment: Note: changing the order of the code in JS didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put a variable (`item` in this case) in a string and expect it to place it's value instead. (*That can be done in PHP.*) For the compiler, it's just a string. You just have to take it out of the double quotes.
Hence, the statement:

```
$("<li class='tile'>+ item +</li>").prependTo(".shopping_item_list");`
```

should be:

```
$("<li class='tile'>" + item + "</li>").prependTo(".shopping_item_list");
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I can see the new list item flash on the page when I change the code to yours. However, I think that the page is refreshing itself when "enter" is pressed in the input box so the new item is added and then disappears. What can I do to prevent this and make the new item stay on page load?

Comment: May be you have put `type='submit'` to the button which adds the item. OR some other javascript code is submitting the page. Are you using asp.net?

Comment: No I'm not. I don't even know what asp.net is. :) I'm just learning jquery now and then will move into javascript. I prefer not to have a submit button if I can, because the design looks cleaner without it.

Comment: I was able to prevent the page refresh with this in my HTML: <form  onsubmit="return false">

Answer (score 0):

change to this:

```
$("#shoppingItem").change(function() { 
    var item = $(this).val();   
    $("<li class='tile'>"+item+"</li>").prependTo(".shopping_item_list");
    $(".tile").removeClass("middle");   
    $(".shopping_item_list li:nth-child(3n+2)").addClass("middle");
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WY4gU/1/)